# Get a table from a website to a CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I need to transform the tables from a website to a CSV file. 
I am using Python 3 from a raspberryPi.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request, URLError
from TableParser import TableParser
url_addr ='http://www.tbs-sct.gc.ca/pses-saff/2017-2/results-resultats/bq-pq/12/org-eng.aspx#s1'
req = Request(url_addr)
url = urlopen(req)
tp = TableParser()
tp.feed(url.read())

#Here I want the first table
my_table = tp.get_tables()[0]
filename = 'table_as_csv.csv'
f = open(filename, 'wb')
with f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in table:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

When I try to run it, I get:
    ImportError: No module named 'TableParser'.

I am new to Python and I don't know what to do. Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you should familiarise yourself with python and its syntax as well as how it handles errors. Clearly you want to do something quick and be done with it. Here's [a simple python tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm)

**To answer your question**

`ImportError` exceptions occur when you do not have that particular module installed using pip installation preferrably. Until it is installed your script wont run successfully.

The error means `TableParser` has not been installed yet and you could do this by

```
pip3 install TableParser
```

This assumes you know where the module is and can be installed using pip

I see you are using the module `csv` but have not imported it as well. You should.